# How to Setup particular Programs in Windows7 Administrator access to Non-Admin User

Tags: visual-studio-2010, security, windows-7, uac

I have team of developers in my company, and i have windows7 installed with `UAC` on all the machines, now the Dotnetnuke Compiled Template require Administrator access to create, because they are linked with IIS, so everytime they want to work on DNN Modules, they calls me to input the Credentials, and if they by-mistake close the VS, they again my Credentials, is there a way to run only Particular Application with Administrator on Standard User Accounts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible.
It is even more complicated if your users are not in Administrators group. In this case the admin access token is not stripped from their security token, they never had it in the first place.

To start an elevated process, users must provide administrator privileges if they are not member of Administrators group. If they are, then a simple confirmation is shown.